# Finding occurances by comparing 2 columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
d = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
     'col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','D'],
     'col2':['C','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'F','G','H'],
     'data':['abc','def','ghk','lmn','opq','rst','uvw','xyz']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to find all values in col2 for each unique value in col1. Think of `col1` as being a house and `col2` as the number of devices in it.

Output:

```
col1    col2    data
 A       C       abc
                 def
         D       ghk
 B       E       lmn
         F       opq
                 rst
 C       G       uvw
 D       H       xyz
```

Update:
Since I have a large number of rows in my original dataset(98k rows), would it be great if I could get a list of values from `col1` which have more than one row in col2. Based on my Output, I would need a list with values `['A','B']`

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])`?

Comment: Nope this doesnt work. I want the desired output.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji it appears you are being pedantic in regards to "matching" your desired output.  I must point out that you depiction of your desired output implies that you have a `MultiIndex` in which the first level is `'col'` and the second level is `'col2'` and **NO** data.  More explicitly stated, your depicted output is not possible (at least not without extreme torturing of the data).  In that case, instead of dismissing the suggestion with a "Nope" please add more information.  As far as I can tell, Quang's suggestion is optimal.  That's advice from **two** knowledgeable Pandas users.

Comment: I apologise if it came off as rude or pedantic, col1 and col2 are location values , think like `col1` is a house, and `col2` is the number of devices in it. I have already dropped all duplicates from my dataframe , that's why my id is unique. I did not understand the solution provided by @QuangHoang , perhaps I shouldv asked more about it. I will be more careful from now on. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: When I said "you are being pedantic", I am stating that you are requiring a very strict adherence to your desired output.  My subsequent statement implies that you cannot strictly adhere to your desired output.  I **didn't** imply that you were being rude.  I'm merely stating that your response and expectations are **NOT** consistent and that you should edit your post to make them consistent.

Comment: @QuangHoang Your comment gives me correct answer. If you would like to write it as an answer , I will approve it as correct.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji I have updated the answer with export options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on getting exactly that output, here's one way:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[
    'col1', 'col2'
]).drop('id', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df['col1'] = np.where(df.col1.duplicated()==True, '', df.col1)
```

Which produces:

```
    col1    col2
0   A       C
1           D
2   B       E
3           F
```

You might even want to go as far as:

```
df = df.set_index('col1')
```

Which produces:

```
      col2
col1    
A     C
      D
B     E
      F
```

To export to `csv` or `excel` simply do one of the following:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

**UPDATE**: Based on the update in the question, the list of values from `col1` can be obtained as follows:

```
list(df.groupby('col1').col1.filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).unique())
```

Which produces:

```
['A', 'B']
```

Comment: I verified your output, its not consistent. Check @Quang Hoang comment. That is simpler and works.

Comment: Works as expected on your example. And both cases use the `drop_duplicates()` so I'm not sure what you mean "it's not consistent".

Comment: My total row counts on my dataset vary by huge number between your answer and @Quang Hoang's answer. If you see what  @piRSquared mentioned, generating multi index output is complicated , which you are doing, but I am losing huge number of rows in that. I care more about `col2` being unique, hence his answer is safer for me. Thank you for your effort, I am not a pro so I cant really tell you why exactly your answer is not working for me.

Comment: Again `drop_duplicates()` based on the subset `['col1', 'col2']` in both cases, so I doubt that you suddenly end up "losing huge number of rows". Also, there's no point in providing example data if it doesn't represent your situation. That's just confusing for everyone, including yourself. That being said, good luck solving whatever issue it is that you have. Cheers!

Comment: @MurtazaHaji I have updated with how you can produce that list. Feel free to accept if it helped you.

Comment: I went through your answer , the drop_duplicates works exactly right, but when I use the np.where , its not indexing correctly. I will try to provide a reproducible example if possible. Thanks for the list function, that will help me test out the rows. I could ping you seperately if you would like to discuss this further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212717/discussion-between-murtaza-haji-and-chrd).

Comment: Simple but elegant and kind of gave me what I wanted.  `df1 = df.set_index(['col1','col2'])`

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby()` with an application of `unique()`:

```
In [26]: df.groupby('col1').col2.unique()         
Out[26]: 
col1
A    [C, D]
B    [E, F]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: This gives me correct output. How can we make the output in two seperate columns? I would like to export as csv or excel

Comment: @MurtazaHaji have you checked my solution? I believe it gives you the output you want.